# VT50 Reverse Linefeed

Tags: vt52

The DECscope User's manual (EK-VT5X-OP-001, 4th printing, March 1977) states (page 19) that Reverse Line Feed is VT52/VT55 only:

> Reverse Line Feed (**VT52 only**)
>
> invoked by ESC I (033 111)
>
> ...

However, vt50h termcap/terminfo entries, dating back at least to [2BSD](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=2BSD/bin/etc/termcap) (1980), include reverse linefeed. (vt50 termcap/terminfo entries do not).

```
$ infocmp vt50h
#   Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/76/vt50h
vt50h|dec vt50h,
    cols#80, lines#12,
    bel=^G, clear=\EH\EJ, cr=^M, cub1=^H, cud1=^J, cuf1=\EC,
    cup=\EY%p1%' '%+%c%p2%' '%+%c, cuu1=\EA, ed=\EJ, el=\EK,
    ht=^I, ind=^J, ri=\EI,
```

Did the VT50h support reverse linefeed?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is a mistake from the terminfo entry (it wouldn't be the first).

The only difference between the VT50 and VT50H is the keypad, not the command set, and another document from DEC: [VT50 user's manual](http://www.bitsavers.org/www.computer.museum.uq.edu.au/pdf/DEC-00-HVTUA-A-D%20VT50%20Video%20Terminal.pdf) (issued in 1975), clearly indicates, consistently with the document you mentioned, that "ESC I" has no effect on the VT50 (see page 19).

There is no reason *not* to trust both these documents from DEC.

I personally have, on the other hand, more than one reason to distrust a terminfo entry.

Comment: Per the DECScope user manual, VT50H also supported cursor down (ESC B) and Direct cursor addressing (ESC Y or SO).

Comment: @KelvinSherlock You are right, there are some differences in the command set between the VT50 and VT50H, that I wasn't aware of. Well, I am still convinced that if there is a mistake somewhere, it is much more likely to be in the terminfo than in the DECscope manual, but since I was using the hypothesis that both VT50 and VT50H have the same command set in my answer, and I am unable to find a specific manual for VT50H, I wonder what to do with my answer. Shall I delete it?

Comment: It's a good answer (and following your link I did find the [service notes](http://www.bitsavers.org/www.computer.museum.uq.edu.au/pdf/VT50%20Service%20Notes.pdf) which includes the vt50 microprogramming).  Short of digging up the VT50H microprogramming or someone actually testing, it's probably the correct answer.